# Can I use Firebase Analytics to fetch data from an Android app and show it on a Java Swing desktop app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swing, firebase-analytics

I have an Android application which is a social network based on movies. People can search for movies and create personalized movie lists, but also add friends and use basic social media functionalities.

I already use FirebaseFirestore as a database and FirebaseAuth to authenticate users, but I would like to be able to use Analytics in order to store data such as number of users, number of movie searches, most popular movies etc.

My question is: can I view these statistics on a completely separate desktop app, built in Java Swing on Eclipse, which would act as a sort of admin console for my application?

Comment: I haven't found anything this specific on the Firebase documentation

Comment: i think i understand what you're asking now, you're asking if there's a java (not android) equivalent of the analytics library, right ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody he is asking to show the analytics stats in an external desktop application instead of the firebase dashboard.

Comment: @Anshul1507 yes, are you aware of any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query your analytics data from the [Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) in your Java Swing desktop app.